# Call a Angular 7 component from another component using window.open()

Tags: angular, angular7

I am using Angular 7 in my project. I have a total of 3 components in my application.all components are at the same level (means the path of the components are at the same level)

I want to call a component on button click from a different component but at that time I don,t want to refresh my page. I just want to show the data in that new window.

can anyone suggest How can I achieve this thing in my Angular 7 application? 
below is my approach

```
<button (click)="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

calling of the component in type script is as follows.

```
myFunction() {
  window.open("http://localhost:4200/#/pages/search");
}
```

In the above function search is my component name. the UI of this component page I want to show in that window. In the search component, I have `search.component.html` and other `ts` files.

So basically whenever I click on the button it should call that component so that in that new window I can show the UI of the component that I am calling.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: DO you want to show the component in a new browser tab?

Comment: yes it will be in a new browser but it should not open in a full window, it should open in half window just like the window.open functionalities.

Comment: I think you should try doing this in a modal box rather than a new window

Comment: @Saksham, the requirement is that if I click on the button then it should open a new window (not the full window half size window). then it should be minimized and if I again click on the button then it will again open that window. so that at the same time it should manage two different windows.

Comment: Alright. I have added the suggested solution, if that works for you

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for router service. This will help you navigate between different components. A small example below. Bind the click event as

```
<a (click)="RouteToComponent()">Click ME</a>
```

And use the `navigate` method to navigate to the required route on click.

```
RouteToComponent():void {
    this._router.navigate(['/ComponentRoute']);
}
```

Don't forget to inject the router service in your component's constructor as

```
constructor(private _router: Router) { }
```

And import Router service as

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router'
```

**Edit:** As the OP wants to open it in a new window, one can use the target attribute as

```
<a target="_blank" [routerLink]="['/ComponentRoute']">Click ME</a>
```

**Edit 2:** As the window should be a smaller one,

```
RouteToComponent():void {
    window.open (window.location.origin + "/ComponentRoute","My Component","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=350,height=250");
}
```

More information on [window.open](http://javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml)

Comment: and this line of code `_router.navigate(['ComponentRoute'])` would work? And does it also open a new browser window?

Comment: @AJT_82 I think I forgot to add the forward slash. I misunderstood OPs requirement which he cleared after I posted the potential solution.

Comment: I think it still would complain about `Cannot find name '_router'....` ;) I don't see that OP has changed their question, it's been the same since beginning, but surely we all misunderstand questions :)

Comment: @AJT_82 sorry but I am a beginner as well, can you be specific on what I have missed. I think it was the import statement which I added and I assume that the OP will import the module and declare the routes array.

Comment: You have forgotten a `this`, specifically should be: `this._router.navigate(['/ComponentRoute']);` :)

Answer (score 0):

**Option A, Angular Router (Recomended)**

it enables navigation from one view to the next as users perform application tasks.

you need to create routes and assign to components

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'route-1', component: Component1},
  { path: 'route-2', component: Component2},
}
```

use a router outlet

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

and on a element put this attribute

```
<element routerLink="/route-1"></element>
```

https://run.stackblitz.com/api/angular/v1

**Option B, Use a variable to hide/show components**

Variable in ts TS

```
export class AppComponent {
  option= "A"
}
```

HTML

```
<a (click)="option='A'">Component A</a>
<a (click)="option='B'">Component B</a>
<a (click)="option='B'">Component C</a>

<component-A*ngIf="option=='A'"></A>
<component-B*ngIf="option=='B'"></A>
<component-C*ngIf="option=='C'"></A>
```